# I cannot use de.archive.ubuntu for updates

Tags: apt

For two weeks I have been unable to use `.de.archive.ubuntu` for:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Welcome, do you mean `http://de.archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: Show us what happens when you apt update please

Comment: Show us all the output from `sudo apt-get update` please.

Comment: Change to main server the German mirror is current not available.

Comment: @nobody Cannot confirm (tested all IP resolutions for de.archive.ubuntu.com, they're all "online") - without the exact errors being seen here by you or OP we can't verify issues with the mirror.